# Spring webflow validation

Tags: spring, validation, spring-webflow

complete and utter newbie on spring webflow (and indeed, spring mvc).
30 minutes in... got the first page of my flow appearing, which happens to be a captcha, an input field and a submit button.

The actual captcha value is stored in session and i need to validate that the input field values matches the value in session.

In order to do validation, my model is passed a 'ValidationContext'.

Question: i can't seem to access session data from the ValidationContext.  How do i do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try MessageContext in place of validationContext

Answer (score 0):

In spring webflow we have a model class and a model validator class. Make sure you have created a validator method in the validator class and it  must have same name as the method you are trying to validate (The method where you have those input fields). This should give you a guideline on getting started.